# Convert processing to javascript

Tags: javascript, css, processing

I wrote this code in processing which allows an image to move vertically based on where the mouse position is. Now I want to post it on a website and understand why the code needs to be converted to javascript.

```
float xpos1;
int one = 0;
PImage alpha;


void setup()
{
  alpha = loadImage("Alpha.png");
  size (800, 300);
  smooth();
  xpos1 = width/2;
  }

  void draw() {
    fill(0, 55);
    rect(0, 0, width, height);
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 200);
    float mx = mouseX * 0.4 - width/5.0;

  xpos1 += mx/8;

  if(xpos1 < -700) { xpos1 = width;}
  if(xpos1 > width) { xpos1= -700;}

 image(alpha, xpos1, 90); 

}
```

Is it best or even possible to convert or is it best to do it from scratch in another way?

Comment: [Processing](https://processing.org/) is based on [Java](https://www.java.com/en/about/whatis_java.jsp?bucket_value=desktop-chrome76-windows10-64bit&in_query=no). If you want to wirte similar code, which is able to run in a browser, t hen you've to use [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) which is based on javascript.

Comment: Say that you manage to convert this file to Javascript. Then you "upload it to a website" (meaning, you transfer it to a server somewhere), then what? How will this file be loaded and executed? In what environment? Do you have an HTML page loading it, something? I'm puzzled

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks for answer. Yes I have a web page where I can upload it to. I've done that before. But never from a processing script and I'm not there yet to convert this to a functional javascript language. I understand that this need to be transformed and linked to both html and css but wondered if there was an easy way to just take this code and change it a little bit.

Comment: This question is not too broad, because in context of [Processing](https://processing.org/) there is a clear and short answer.

Comment: @Rabbid76: The question is "too broad" in the sence that it asks about converting a piece of code from one language to another without specifying **which part** (functions, lines) is problematic (assuming converting other part has been performed successfully and is outside of the question scope). In short, asking for equivalent for a specific function, related functions or for a specific functionality is perfectly OK, but asking about converting "just code" is an equivalent for the many questions at once and is "too broad".

Answer (score 4):

[Processing](https://processing.org/) is based on [Java](https://www.java.com/en/about/whatis_java.jsp?bucket_value=desktop-chrome76-windows10-64bit&in_query=no). If you want to wirte similar code, which is able to run in a browser, then you've to use [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) which is based on [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_js.asp) and related to [Processing](https://processing.org/).
Java is not JavaScript

See the example:

```js
var alpha, xpos1, one = 0;

function setup()
{
    alpha = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/ball64.png");
    createCanvas(800, 300);
    smooth();
    xpos1 = width/2;
}

function draw() {
    fill(0, 55);
    rect(0, 0, width, height);
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 200);
    mx = mouseX * 0.4 - width/5.0;

    xpos1 += mx/8;

    if(xpos1 < -700) { xpos1 = width;}
    if(xpos1 > width) { xpos1= -700;}

    image(alpha, xpos1, 90); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Note, the functions and interfaces which are provided by *p5.js* are in a wide scale equal that one of *Processing*, but differ in many details. 
But both APIs (respectively libraries) are well documented. See [p5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) respectively [Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/)